# Xamarin Visual Studio for MAC. Automatic Provisioning failed: An App ID with Identifier '*' is not available

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Until recently I was able to use the auto signing in Visual Studio MAC to handle my provisioning.

Now I get this when trying to build debug and production releases.  I've tried to use the manual provision profiles and those aren't working either.

There is a valid bundle id, same one that's been in place for 3 years, but from the error message it looks like it's confused.

Any suggestions on coming up with a resolution or even some steps to take?

> Fetching valid and locally installed signing identities... Syncing
>   certificates for "Acme, LLC" team... Saving iOS Development
>   certificates... Syncing App IDs for "goidit, LLC" team... Creating a
>   new wildcard App ID... Creating new App ID named VS Wildcard...
>
> Automatic Provisioning failed: An App ID with Identifier '*' is not
>   available. Please enter a different string.

Comment: Have you tried to creat a new App ID?

Comment: I confirm the same issue. In xcode all work fine, only vs studio mac fail

Comment: Any luck? I'm having the same issue? If you found an answer you could answer your question.

Comment: I've only been able to get this to work via manual signing.  Creating a new apple id unfortunately isn't an option.

Comment: Doesn't work here either

Comment: I also faced this issue when I tried to work with Automatic signing. At first manual signing also not worked for me. Now at least manual signing is working fine. For that, I have created XCode project with same bundle id and there automatic provisioning profile works. Then I have used the manual signing option in Visual Studio Mac and also chosen the same signing identity used in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio Mac. I found a [comment on the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/358757/#Comment_358757) that worked for me. I had a couple of old wildcard app identifiers in my developer.apple.com account. Once I deleted them the automatic provisioning worked as advertised.